# Would like a php version of php 8.1 for a specific virtual website

Tags: php, ubuntu-18.04, laravel-9

I have a virtual website in an ubuntu 18.04 server that is written in Laravel9 and it needs php version 8.0.2 or higher. The error looks like this in the browser:

Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.0.2".

In the system I have PHP 7.4.29 (cli) but can't change that due to other virtual sites who need 7.4.

How do I get php 8.1 to the Laravel9 site so it works?

Comment: Spin up another server or run the app in a container. Maintaining multiple versions of PHP on the same server is a pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found out that what was needed was a composer command:

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

So now no error anymore. Now I have other things to worry about, but thats Laravel stuff.

My other sites works ok despite php 8.1 now.

Thanks any way for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If using Debian/Ubuntu:

```sh
apt -y install software-properties-common
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
apt -y install php8.1
```

CentOS:

```sh
dnf install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm
dnf install dnf-utils http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-8.rpm

dnf remove php* -y
dnf module list reset php -y
dnf module enable php:remi-8.1
dnf install php
```

Comment: Done that, no change. Same error in the browser. And in terminal: php -v = PHP 8.1.5 (cli)

Comment: @raffodog what do you mean, 'done that'? Didn't you say in your question that "can't change that due to other virtual sites who need 7.4"? So what version your sites require, 7.4 or 8.1?